# First-stage IV regression results in plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, economics

Is there a way to report first-stage instrumental variable regression using the `plm` package?

For example, using the `lfe` package, one can use `summary(lfe_model$stage1)` to report the first-stage regression.

Comment: By the first stage of the  `plm` you mean the first stage of the Two Stage Least Squares method for instrumental variables? At least, that is the method `lfe` employs. `plm`, by its turn, uses the "Balestra and Varadharajan-Krishnakumar" or "baltagi" methods, as described [here][1] in page 17. You must have in mind that these methods not necesserly makes use of a multiple steps. I know this is vague, but with theses references you can get more details of the routines being employed by `plm`. 


  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, that is what I mean. So if I understand your comment correctly, you are saying that `lfe` employs the 2SLS method for IV regression, while the `plm` employs a different method (that does not involve 2SLS and therefore first-stage regression doesn't exist, to begin with) - is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's partialy right as long I don't have enough knowledge of the methods `plm` employs, but the cited reference is a starting point. The `lfe` package, however, explicitly says it uses 2SLS as default. For sake of completeness, mind that 2SLS is just case when te GMM estimator is exactly identified, which mean you can make use of the one-step GMM estimator and get the same results. My guess, and not more than a guess, is that `plm` does something similar to this.